# iOS hitTest fails during portrait to landscape rotation

Tags: ios

Trying to debug a weird issue.

I have a Class that inherits from UIView, which contains a UIScrollView. The scrollview is only a fraction of the size of the view, so inorder for the entire view to capture the touch/scroll and send it to the UIScrolLView, I've overwritten the hitTest method for UIView.

```
- (UIView *) hitTest: (CGPoint) point withEvent: (UIEvent *) event 
{
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) 
    {
        return _scroller;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

If I show the view in portrait, then rotate to landscape, the hitTest response doesn't rotate appropriately. If I hide the view, and reshow it, it works as I expect.

However, if I show the view in landscape, then rotate to portrait, the hitTest response behaves as we expect.

I'm looking at a workaround (during rotation, hide, then reshow the view), but I'd like to avoid using this hack.

Any thoughts?